# Updating JavaFX GUI from a service thread

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

How can I safely update the widgets on a JavaFX GUI from within a JavaFX Service.  I remember when I was developing with Swing, I used to 'invoke later' and other various swing worker utilities to ensure that all updates to the UI were handled safely in the Java Event Thread.  Here is an example of a simple service thread that handles datagram messages.  The bit that is missing is where the datagram message is parsed and corresponding UI widgets are updated.  As you can see the service class is very simplistic.

I'm not sure if I need to use simple binding properties (like message) or alternatively should I should pass widgets to the constructor of my StatusListenerService (which is probably not the best thing to do). Can someone give me a good similar example that I would work from.

```
public class StatusListenerService extends Service<Void> {
    private final int mPortNum;

    /**
     *
     * @param aPortNum server listen port for inbound status messages
     */
    public StatusListenerService(final int aPortNum) {
        this.mPortNum = aPortNum;
    }

    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {
        return new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                updateMessage("Running...");
                try {
                    DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(mPortNum);
                    // allocate space for received datagrams
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[512];
                    //message.setByteBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes), 0);
                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(bytes, bytes.length);                    
                    while (!isCancelled()) {                    
                        serverSocket.receive(packet);
                        SystemStatusMessage message = new SystemStatusMessage();
                        message.setByteBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes), 0);                         
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
                updateMessage("Cancelled");
                return null;
            } 
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "low-level" approach is to use `Platform.runLater(Runnable r)` to update the UI. This will execute `r` on the FX Application Thread, and is the equivalent of Swing's `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`. So one approach is simply to call `Platform.runLater(...)` from inside your `call()` method and update the UI. As you point out, though, this essentially requires the service knowing details of the UI, which is undesirable (though there are patterns that work around this).

`Task` defines some properties and has corresponding `updateXXX` methods, such as the `updateMessage(...)` method you call in your example code. These methods are safe to call from any thread, and result in an update to the corresponding property to be executed on the FX Application Thread. (So, in your example, you can safely bind the text of a label to the `messageProperty` of the service.) As well as ensuring the updates are performed on the correct thread, these `updateXXX` methods also throttle the updates, so that you can essentially call them as often as you like without flooding the FX Application Thread with too many events to process: updates that occur within a single frame of the UI will be coalesced so that only the last such update (within a given frame) is visible.

You could leverage this to update the `valueProperty` of the task/service, if it is appropriate for your use case. So if you have some (preferably immutable) class that represents the result of parsing the packet (let's call it `PacketData`; but maybe it is as simple as a `String`), you make

```
public class StatusListener implements Service<PacketData> {

   // ...

   @Override
   protected Task<PacketData> createTask() {
      return new Task<PacketData>() {
          // ...

          @Override
          public PacketData call() {
              // ...
              while (! isCancelled()) { 
                  // receive packet, parse data, and wrap results:
                  PacketData data = new PacketData(...);
                  updateValue(data);
              }
              return null ;
          }
      };
   }
}
```

Now you can do

```
StatusListener listener = new StatusListener();
listener.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    // update UI with newValue...
});
listener.start();
```

Note that the value is updated to `null` by the code when the service is cancelled, so with the implementation I outlined you need to make sure that your listener on the `valueProperty()` handles this case.

Also note that this will coalesce consecutive calls to `updateValue()` if they occur within the same frame rendering. So this is **not** an appropriate approach if you need to be sure to process *every* data in your handler (though typically such functionality would not need to be performed on the FX Application Thread anyway). This is a good approach if your UI is only going to need to show the "most recent state" of the background process.

SSCCE showing this technique:

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LongRunningTaskExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        CheckBox enabled = new CheckBox("Enabled");
        enabled.setDisable(true);
        CheckBox activated = new CheckBox("Activated");
        activated.setDisable(true);
        Label name = new Label();
        Label value = new Label();

        Label serviceStatus = new Label();

        StatusService service = new StatusService();
        serviceStatus.textProperty().bind(service.messageProperty());

        service.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue == null) {
                enabled.setSelected(false);
                activated.setSelected(false);
                name.setText("");
                value.setText("");
            } else {
                enabled.setSelected(newValue.isEnabled());
                activated.setSelected(newValue.isActivated());
                name.setText(newValue.getName());
                value.setText("Value: "+newValue.getValue());
            }
        });

        Button startStop = new Button();
        startStop.textProperty().bind(Bindings
                .when(service.runningProperty())
                .then("Stop")
                .otherwise("Start"));

        startStop.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (service.isRunning()) {
                service.cancel() ;
            } else {
                service.restart();
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(5, serviceStatus, name, value, enabled, activated, startStop);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static class StatusService extends Service<Status> {
        @Override
        protected Task<Status> createTask() {
            return new Task<Status>() {
                @Override
                protected Status call() throws Exception {
                    Random rng = new Random();
                    updateMessage("Running");
                    while (! isCancelled()) {

                        // mimic sporadic data feed:
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(rng.nextInt(2000));
                        } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                            if (isCancelled()) {
                                break ;
                            }
                        }

                        Status status = new Status("Status "+rng.nextInt(100), 
                                rng.nextInt(100), rng.nextBoolean(), rng.nextBoolean());
                        updateValue(status);
                    }
                    updateMessage("Cancelled");
                    return null ;
                }
            };
        }
    }

    private static class Status {
        private final boolean enabled ; 
        private final boolean activated ;
        private final String name ;
        private final int value ;

        public Status(String name, int value, boolean enabled, boolean activated) {
            this.name = name ;
            this.value = value ;
            this.enabled = enabled ;
            this.activated = activated ;
        }

        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return enabled;
        }

        public boolean isActivated() {
            return activated;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the detail in your answer.  The thing about my service is that it is long running so as each packet arrives (it may affect 4 or 5 checkbox states and potentially a few text fields).  Should I create custom properties (similar to Value) for each of these widgets and somehow tie these into my StatusListener service.  Does that sound familiar or am I way off base? I like the fact that updates are coalesced - useful when the network traffic is heavy - I used to use a similar feature from SwingWorker back when I was developing in using swing.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Using the structure I suggested you would just encapsulate all that data (i.e. 4 or 5 booleans and potentially a few Strings) in the class I called `PacketData`, though you would obviously have a more meaningful name for it. Then just unpack the data in the listener and update the UI accordingly.

Comment: In my case my task returns a <void> essentially it runs forever - in the case of the example you show it returns a PacketData - presumably once per datagram - the idea I had was that the service would run until the application finished - maybe I am going about this the wrong way

Comment: My example also only exits when cancelled, and at that point returns `null` (updating the value). Note I still have the same `while` loop: it can run as long as you want. But it also updates the value as packets are processed, and that value is still observable from the UI. You actually probably don't need a `Service` at all, and could just use a single `Task`, though you may want the ability to restart after a user cancelation. This is basically the example under "A Task which returns partial results" in the [`Task` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html)

Comment: @johnco3 The extensive documentation for [Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) and [Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) is recommended reading;  it has plenty of examples.  The latter even has a section titled “A Task Which Modifies The Scene Graph.”

Comment: Updated with example.